# Chocolate graham crust

Tags: baking

Is there any way of making a regular graham cracker crust into a Chocolate graham cracker crust?

Comment: Chocolate teddy grahams?

Comment: Are you asking about whether you can substitute chocolate graham crackers for regular in a recipe? Or how to add chocolate/cocoa to a recipe (still using regular crackers)? Or modifying an already-made crust?

Answer (score 1):

You can use chocolate graham crackers to replace the graham crackers as an easy way, though they're not *that* chocolate-y. There are also tons of recipes out there that add cocoa powder (just [google "graham cracker crust cocoa powder"](https://www.google.com/search?q=graham%20cracker%20crust%20cocoa%20powder)). Amounts vary wildly, from 2 tablespoons to 2/3 cup, though the ones on the higher end add more butter to make it work. You could do both if you want to get as much chocolate in as possible.

If you mean a pre-made crust, I don't see how you can really do anything. The best I can think of is lining the crust with a layer of chocolate or chocolate ganache - just melt chocolate, add cream if you want a ganache, and spread it inside the crust.

Comment: I think sone sugar would need to be added too, wouldn't it since cocoa powder is unsweetened?

Comment: @Jude Possibly, but I think it's optional - there's already sugar in a normal graham cracker crust recipe, so you can think of it as adding chocolate flavor to something that's already a reasonable sweetness.